# Place a View accordingly another different view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

I was looking for way to achieve below design in android. I have two different image slices

- Chat bubble
- Z icon

I want to know if there is way to place **Z icon under that arrow of chat bubble** pragmatically.

Here i want to avoid the way by giving some different margin for all different set of devices.

[image]

Comment: I dont want to give some predefined margin to place those icon .

Comment: `LinearLayout`? One view is above another. What's the problem?

Comment: Why dont u use 9-patch drawable image for chat bubble?

Comment: i want Z icon under that arrow for all device , i don't want fix margin to achieve

Comment: Is chat bubble an image?

Comment: this is the only possible by using co-ordinate and size of Z image with calculation

Comment: @Ajit yes , this is the question all about